# error 1004 MACRO de Filtrado Excel

Tags: excel, filtro, macros, vb

Hola esta es la primera MACRO que uso en Excel, por lo que vi en la comunidad de Analistas es muy sencilla, pero me marca este error:

> "Error 1004" "Error en el método Autofilter de la clase Range".

Estoy haciendo un tabla muy sencilla con datos de personal de una tienda, [nombre, dirección, teléfono, municipio, etc.] Quiero usar este filtro solo en la columna de Nombre. La cabecera de la columna es en A1 los datos empiezan en A2. Quiero que filtre toda la información de la fila con ese nombre. Les dejo el código.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

filtro = "*" & Sheets("Hoja1").TextBox1.Text & "*"
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field = 1, Criterial = filtro

End Sub
```

De antemano gracias por responder.

Answer (score 0):

No tengo forma de probar tu código pues no tengo tu archivo, pero por si acaso los valores de los parámetros del método AutoFilter, y otros, se dan usando dos puntos e igual y, además, veo una L después de "Criteria", debe ir un uno (1):

```
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field := 1, Criteria1 := filtro
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Abraham Valencia. Hice las correcciones que mencionas y la MACRO funciona muy bien.